# Can the Wiener-Khinchin theorem be correctly applied to a periodic sound signal (such as a sine wave)?

Tags: signal-processing, correlation, applications, stationary-processes

The theorem speaks about a wide-sense stationary random process. Is, for example, a sine wave with a period 1/400 s considered a WSS (or, in general, a periodic sound signal with multiple frequency components)? I'm especially asking about whether the randomness aspect is fulfilled, and if not, how does this change the mathematical expression of the theorem? Is it still fair to say that the Fourier transform of the autocorrelation function of a periodic sound signal is equal to the power spectral density of the signal?